# Why does this 'fold array' function return less elements than expected?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a function that folds an array at the middle index. It takes in an 'array' of any length. It takes in an integer for the number of fold or 'runs.'

It aims to return an array with the elements added like so:

Fold 1-times:
[1,2,3,4,5] -> [6,6,3]

A little visualisation:

```
 Step 1         Step 2        Step 3       Step 4       Step5
                     5/           5|         5\          
                    4/            4|          4\      
1 2 3 4 5      1 2 3/         1 2 3|       1 2 3\       6 6 3
----*----      ----*          ----*        ----*        ----*
```

Fold 2-times:
[1,2,3,4,5] -> [9,6]

This is for a codewars challenge.
I have tried it in terminal and it works.
I have tried tweaking the lines where the array is sliced and mapped, they don't seem to be the cause of the problem.

I have tried adding a variable for the final array output to make sure when the do block runs multiple times it takes in the new array and not the original. This wasn't the problem either.

```
def fold_array(array, runs)
 runs.times do
   if array.length == 1
       array = array
     elsif array.length.even?
        arr2 = array.slice!(array.length/2..-1).reverse!
        final1 = array.zip(arr2).map {|a| a.inject(:+)}
        array = final1
     else
        mi = (array.length/2) 
        mv = array.slice(mi)
        arr2 = array.slice!(mi..-1).reverse!
        final2 = array.zip(arr2).map {|a| a.inject(:+)}
        final2.push(mv)
        array = final2
    end
  end
 array
end
```

input = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], 1
Test Passed: Value == [6, 6, 3]

input = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], 2
Test Failed: Expected: [9, 6], instead got: [3]

input = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], 3
Test Failed: Expected: [15], instead got: [1]

input = [ -9, 9, -8, 8, 66, 23 ], 1
Test Passed: Value == [14, 75, 0]

I get the right result when the number of runs is 1, but when it's 2 or more it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're modifying the input array, which Codewars is reusing in multiple test cases. Do something like `arr = array.dup` as the first line of your function, and then change all subsequent occurrences of `array` in your code to `arr` (or whatever variable name you chose) and then you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks so much Tané Tachyon, this did the business.